How to get the current price and time in TreadView based on X-axis and Y-axis
    widget.onChartReady(function () {
        widget.subscribe('mouse_up', function (params) {
            console.log('mouse_up：' + JSON.stringify(params));
            // params：{"clientX":1232,"clientY":488,"pageX":1232,"pageY":488,"screenX":1473,"screenY":599}
            // How to get the current price and time in TreadView based on X-axis and Y-axis.

使用widget.subscribe()打印出了{"clientX":1452,"clientY":613,"pageX":1452,"pageY":613,"screenX":1693,"screenY":724}我没有找到合适的方法来使用TreadingView转换成对应的时间和价格

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
